# When rewriting tree on ANTLR, java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to create a parser for QuickBasic and this is my attempt to get the comments:

```
grammar QuickBasic;

options 
{
    language = 'CSharp2';
    output = AST;
}

tokens
{
    COMMENT;
}

parse
    :    .* EOF
    ;

// DOESN'T WORK
Comment
    :    R E M t=~('\n')* { Text = $t; } -> ^(COMMENT $t)
    |    Quote t=~('\n')* { Text = $t; } -> ^(COMMENT $t)
    ;

Space  
    :    (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C') { Skip(); }  
    ;

fragment Quote : '\'';    
fragment E     : 'E' | 'e';
fragment M     : 'M' | 'm';
fragment R     : 'R' | 'r';
```

Even if I rewrite using only the token COMMENT and nothing more, I still get the same error.

```
// It DOESN'T WORK EITHER
Comment
    :    (R E M | Quote) ~('\n')* -> ^(COMMENT)
    ;
```

If I give up rewriting, it works:

```
// THIS WORKS
Comment
    :    (R E M | Quote) ~('\n')*
    ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite rules only work with parser rules not with lexer rules. And `t=~('\n')*` will cause only the last non-line-break to be stored in the `t`-label, so that wouldn't have worked anyway.

But why not skip these `Comment` tokens all together. If you leave them in the token stream, you'd need to account for `Comment` tokens in all your parser rules (where `Comment` tokens are valid to occur): not something you'd want, right?

To skip the, simply call `Skip()` at the end of the rule:

```
Comment
    :    R E M ~('\r' | '\n')* { Skip(); }
    |    Quote ~('\r' | '\n')* { Skip(); }
    ;
```

or more concise:

```
Comment
    :    (Quote | R E M) ~('\r' | '\n')* { Skip(); }
    ;
```

However, if you're really keen on leaving `Comment` tokens in the stream and strip either `"rem"` or the quote from the comment, do it like this:

```
Comment
    :    (Quote | R E M) t=NonLineBreaks { Text = $t.text; }
    ;

fragment NonLineBreaks : ~('\r' | '\n')+;
```

You could then also create a parser rule that creates an AST with `COMMENT` as the root (although I don't see the benefit over simply using `Comment`):

```
comment
    :    Comment -> ^(COMMENT Comment)
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks Bart! The real intention behind all this is to transform programs written in QuickBasic to any other language. That's why the comments are important.

Comment: About the COMMENT token... Just removed it. :)