# how to parse only some comments using ANTLRv4

Tags: parsing, comments, antlr, antlr4

I devel application analyzing Java source code using ANTLRv4. I claim to match all single-line comments with first token `TODO` (e.g. `// TODO <some-comment>`) together with directly following statement.

**Sample code:**

```
class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO develop cycle
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // unmatched comment
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
        // TODO atomic
        int a;

        // TODO revision required
        {
            int b = a+4;
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** = **map** like this:

```
"develop cycle" -> for(...){...}
"atomic" -> int a
"revision required" -> {...}
```

Following [official book (1)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356999) and similar topics on stackoverflow ([(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485132/catching-and-keeping-all-comments-with-antlr), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070763/parse-comment-line), [(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007951/special-comment-cannot-match-lexer-rule), [(5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850007/when-rewriting-tree-on-antlr-java-lang-nullpointerexception-is-thrown/10850237), [(6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976617/parsing-single-line-comments)) I tried several ways.

At first I hoped for special COMMENTS channel as described in [(1)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356999) and [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485132/catching-and-keeping-all-comments-with-antlr) but error `rule 'LINE_COMMENT' contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output` occured.

I guess it would be much nicer to parse the source code in a way of ignoring all single-line comments BUT those beginning by `TODO`. I hope it is possible to add todo-comments directly into AST in order to use listeners/walkers. Than I'd only need register listener/walker for TODO comment and extract following statement, adding both to desired **map**.

I've been modifing official [Java8 gammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4) for two days but without any success. Either compiler complains or AST is mismashed.

This is update I made:

```
// ...
COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

TODO_COMMENT
    :   '// TODO' ~[\r\n]*
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;
```

Can anyone help me please? Grammars are not my cup of tea. Thanks in advance

**EDIT1:**

Grammar modification posted above complies without error, but following tree is generated (please note the red marked nodes including `int`)

[image: error AST]

**EDIT2:**

Assuming code sample above, while calling `parser.compilationUnit();` following error is generated

```
line 3:2 extraneous input '// TODO develop cycle;' expecting {'abstract', 'assert', 'boolean', 'break', 'byte', 'char', 'class', 'continue', 'do', 'double', 'enum', 'final', 'float', 'for', 'if', 'int', 'interface', 'long', 'new', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'return', 'short', 'static', 'strictfp', 'super', 'switch', 'synchronized', 'this', 'throw', 'try', 'void', 'while', IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, 'null', '(', '{', '}', ';', '<', '!', '~', '++', '--', '+', '-', Identifier, '@'}
line 8:2 extraneous input '// TODO atomic;' expecting {'abstract', 'assert', 'boolean', 'break', 'byte', 'char', 'class', 'continue', 'do', 'double', 'enum', 'final', 'float', 'for', 'if', 'int', 'interface', 'long', 'new', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'return', 'short', 'static', 'strictfp', 'super', 'switch', 'synchronized', 'this', 'throw', 'try', 'void', 'while', IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, 'null', '(', '{', '}', ';', '<', '!', '~', '++', '--', '+', '-', Identifier, '@'}
line 11:2 extraneous input '// TODO revision required;' expecting {'abstract', 'assert', 'boolean', 'break', 'byte', 'char', 'class', 'continue', 'do', 'double', 'enum', 'final', 'float', 'for', 'if', 'int', 'interface', 'long', 'new', 'private', 'protected', 'public', 'return', 'short', 'static', 'strictfp', 'super', 'switch', 'synchronized', 'this', 'throw', 'try', 'void', 'while', IntegerLiteral, FloatingPointLiteral, BooleanLiteral, CharacterLiteral, StringLiteral, 'null', '(', '{', '}', ';', '<', '!', '~', '++', '--', '+', '-', Identifier, '@'}
```

So obviously grammar is incorect as it struggles with simple example

Comment: What are the exact errors you get for the grammar excerpt above? What kind of mismatches occcur?

Comment: @UweAllner the edit made, please see the scheme provided - Why the `int` is also marked?

Comment: @ptrbel For me this looks quite correct. The int is not part of the `// TODO xxx` but follows it directly in the next block statement subtree. As I understood your problem, this seems really the desired result. What did you expect instead?

Comment: @UweAllner e.g. ANTLR didn't generate `Java8BaseVisitor::visitTODO_COMMENT` - how can I match directly following statement without visitor?

Comment: As you only have a lexer rule for this token, there is no explicit method for that created in the visitor. Instead visitTerminal is called for it. Either you use this method to extract your map key and e.g. set a state "rememberForTodo" in your parser, or you can to define a parser rule (with name beginning with lowercase letter) containing your TODO_COMMENT; then a visitor rule for that is generated.

Comment: @UweAllner I updated the question, could you please take a look at **EDIT2**? How exactly do you mean "define a parse rule"? I tried `todoComment : TODO_COMMENT ;` or even `todoComment : TODO_COMMENT Identifier* ;` which really generated corresponding methods but listener including method `enterTodoComment` was never triggered... Also printage of all terminals doesn't include those TODO comments :-(

Comment: imho the int is only marked because it directly follows the "extra" `TODO_COMMENT`. I would ignore this error especially since the error messages don't report an error for the `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you don't expect your special comment in any parser rule, i.e. no parser will match it.

You can do (at least) something of the following:

1. Add an optional `TODO_COMMENT`? in front of every parser rule.
2. Add the `TODO_COMMENT` token to a separate channel, e.g. `ToDoCommentChannel` (don't forget to define the constant for this channel!) and select each construct that follows a comment in tree-walking.

Rough outline of what I would do:

- Use a separate channel for the `TODO_COMMENT`s.
- lex and parse as usual
- get all tokens from token stream and find those of the desired channel and get the following token on the default channel and store these in a list.
- walk the parse and check for each entered rule if the starting token is in the list. If yes, copy the rules text to your result list, else recurse (if `TODO_COMMENT` can be nested, even recurse when the starting token is in the list).

UPDATE:

About the `rule 'LINE_COMMENT' contains a lexer command with an unrecognized constant value; lexer interpreters may produce incorrect output` error:

This can be ignored since it only affects the interpreter like used by Antlrworks2 or the plugin. You can also do it like this:

```
//Instead of
TODO_COMMENT
    :   '// TODO' ~[\r\n]*  -> channel(ToDoCommentChannel)
    ;    

// do this (assuming the channel value is indeed 42):
TODO_COMMENT
    :   '// TODO' ~[\r\n]*  -> channel(42 /*ToDoCommentChannel*/)
    ;
```

This will work in both Antlrworks2 and the code (you can still use the constant value for the channel in your java runtime code).

Comment: Channels work fine, but I intended to work with TODOs as AST nodes. However, I consider this question as closed, thanks everyone for help :)

Comment: If you want them as nodes (I really don't why you should), use option 1 and put them in front of every location they could occur.